# Problems in reading tab seperated txt file, read.table Error in scan(...) line 7 did not have 4 elements

Tags: r

I'm currently working on a project but got defeated at the very beginning of reading the data. The data has four variables, which are "Label","Book ID","Book Title", and the "Author". And they are separated by "tab", here's a quick look of it,

```
AMERICAN HISTORY    b15857527   These United States Unger, Irwin
AMERICAN HISTORY    b10957081   Cengage Advantage Books: American Passages  Ayers, Edward L.; Gould, Lewis L.; Oshinsky, David M.; Soderlund, Jean R.
AMERICAN HISTORY    b15131495   Voices of a People's History of the United States   Zinn, Howard; Arnove, Anthony
```

Now here are my R codes to read it,

```
train1<-read.table("train1.txt",sep="\t")
```

Then I got this error message,

Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 7 did not have 4 elements

I used the readline function to check whether at line 7 there's no 4 elements, but it seems to be pretty fine,

```
cat(readLines("train1.txt")[1:8], sep = "\n")
AMERICAN HISTORY    b15857527   These United States Unger, Irwin
AMERICAN HISTORY    b10957081   Cengage Advantage Books: American Passages  Ayers, Edward L.; Gould, Lewis L.; Oshinsky, David M.; Soderlund, Jean R.
AMERICAN HISTORY    b15131495   Voices of a People's History of the United States   Zinn, Howard; Arnove, Anthony
AMERICAN HISTORY    b15683513   American Realities  Youngs, J. William T.
AMERICAN HISTORY    b9418230    American History: A Survey, Volume 1    Brinkley, Alan
AMERICAN HISTORY    b14348885   Liberty, Equality, Power    Murrin, John M.; Johnson, Paul E.; McPherson, James M.; Gerstle, Gary; Fahs, Alice
AMERICAN HISTORY    b9372860    American History: A Survey, Volume 2    Brinkley, Alan
AMERICAN HISTORY    b9489206    Religion in America Hemeyer, Julia Corbett
```

I tried to manually adjust it in the original txt file, but no matter what I did, there's always the same error happening at another line, which visibly seems just fine. I would appreciate a lot for any of your generous help, thank you!!

Comment: Bit hard to tell as when you copy/paste the file to SO it converts tabs to spaces. Perhaps check whether one of the "tabs" on line 7 is in fact spaces instead of a tab?

Comment: Can you edit the question and post the output of `dput(readLines("train1.txt", n = 10))`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the apostrophe on line 3. `read.table()` interprets the text following it as one element of line 3, column 3 until the closing apostrophe. Define, what the quote should be:

```
train1 <- read.table("train1.txt", sep="\t", quote="\"")
```